# How to obtain localized string for a number with custom number format?

Tags: ios, swift, double, nsnumberformatter, nslocalizedstring

I'm using `NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(aDouble, numberStyle: .DecimalStyle)` to display a number to the end user. This works well, unless the number has many digits after the decimal.

For example, if `aDouble` is 0.123, the generated string is 0.123 (in English). But if `aDouble` is 0.1234 the string is 0.123.

How can I obtain a localized string for a number but have control over the number of digits displayed? I'd like to show 10-20 digits before rounding.

I don't see an API for creating a custom `numberStyle`, it's restricted to presents like `DecimalStyle` and `ScientificStyle`. I do need it to be a localized representation so that the digits/symbols are displayed properly for the current language/locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of `NSNumberFormatter` and manually set its `locale` and [`maximumFractionDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/maximumFractionDigits) properties:

```
let d = 123.456789012345678

let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10

let formatted = formatter.stringFromNumber(d)
```

> 123.4567890123

There are other properties for setting various digit lengths besides that one. See the [Managing Input and Output Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-SW26) section of the docs.

Comment: Beautiful, that's just fantastic!